# MSVC 2013 не находит подключенные .h файлы

Tags: c++, visual-studio, библиотеки

Доброго дня. Опыта работы с студией не так много и каждый новый проект сталкиваюсь с новыми приключениями. При этом каждый раз исправно следую мануалам:

1) Указываю путь расположения включаемых заголовочных файлов.

2) Указываю путь расположения дополнительных библиотек.

3) Указываю название библиотек.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, особенно в последнее время, получаю ошибки :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слэши пробовал в обе стороны, указывал и в <>, и в "". Предполагаю что проблема с системными переменными, потому как приходилось их редактировать. С студийными переменными всё по умолчанию.

В чём может быть проблема? Понимаю что вопрос уже всем надоел, но тут какой то аномальный случай. Буду рад помощи.

Comment: Вы настроили Release конфигурацию, проверьте, что компилируете в ней же

Comment: Верно, в этом была одна из причин!

Comment: Я сам на этом много шишек набил, поэтому теперь внимательно за этим слежу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что по причине малого опыта работы в MSVC я ошибочно указывал путь к заголовочным фалам и библиотекам в полях Additional Include и Additional Library, не указывая пути в основных директориях проекта на вкладке VC++ Directories:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй причиной был моя ошибка в конфигурации текущего режима сборки. Я настраивал Release, а собирал проект в Active(Debug). 
К системным переменным мои проблемы отношения не имели.

**Вот здесь более подробное описание проблемы:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883276/what-is-the-difference-between-include-directories-and-additional-include-dir